# What type of mood is this main clause in this sentence: “If he comes to apologize, I will forgive him."?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If he comes to apologize, I will forgive him.

When it comes to a conditional type 1 clause, what type of mood is this main clause?

This main clause is a Future indicative?

Or

I had better consider this one just as an only sentence of possible result from If clause with hypothetical condition rather than categorize whether it can be a certain type of mood, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [type 1 conditional with a modal](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/type-1-conditional/#:%7E:text=The%20type%201%20conditional%20refers,world%2C%20and%20about%20particular%20situations.&text=In%20type%201%20conditional%20sentences,and%20the%20situation%20is%20real.) in the main clause would be an OK description for this; see the last example where it reads "if you buy me school supplies, I will be able to go to the park."

Comment: Hi, I mean, This main clause is a Future indicative?